# Issue on multiple date picker

Tags: android, datepicker

I'd like to set a date interval, and when the user presses the end date, draw a chart. The problem i have is that the chart is drawn both on the start and the end date.

I've tried to set a boolean variable or an int to decide when the chart should be drawn, but as i'm using "onDateSet" from "DatePickerFragmet", i cannot modify its parameters... I paste my code here to help clarify what i'm trying to explain:

On my main activity i have:

```
startDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
            showDatePickerDialog(v,i);
        }
    }
});

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v, int i) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

}
```

Then on a new class i call onDateSet:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment 
                implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    LineGraph lineGraph = new LineGraph();
    lineGraph.run(getActivity());

}
```

... How could i draw the chart when the final date is selected?

Answer (score 3):

Write a if..else or a switch statement based on the Tag passed in the `newFragment.show();`

Here you will have to write a `showDatePickerDialog()` method for every date picker separately so that each hold a different tag.
I have implemented it as follows:

```
public void showDeadlineDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "deadlineDate");
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    StringBuilder task = new StringBuilder();
     task.append(day);
     task.append(".");
     task.append(month+1);
     task.append(".");
     task.append(year);
     String x=task.toString();
     if (getTag()=="deadlineDate")
        {

            btn=(Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_deadline_date);
            btn.setText(x);


        }
     if (getTag()=="reminderDate")
     {
         btn=(Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_reminder_date);
         btn.setText(x);

     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had solved this using 2 different classes, as shown below, one for the start date, and another one for the end date. But I find your solution more efficient. Thank you.

Besides, I decided to get rid of the "for" loop and have 2 buttons instead.

Comment: I think @Palak Bheda should use `getTag().equals("deadlineDate")` instead of using `==` in the if statement.

Comment: There's no method named getTag() under onDateSet(). Can you please take a look?

Comment: You can take a look here how they used setCallBack method to pass a specific callback - http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.com/2012/10/creating-datepicker-using.html

Answer (score 0):

As I can't find a way to do this as I mentioned before, I've reached a solution by having 2 buttons (start and end) to select the dates, instead of only havin one and use a loop.
After that, i created another class, and each button calls a different class.

Declaration of the buttons and the methods "showStartDatePicker" and "showEndDatePicker":

```
final Button startDate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startDate);
final Button endDate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.endDate);

public void showStartDatePicker(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new StartDatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "StartDatePicker");
}

public void showEndDatePicker(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new EndDatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "EndDatePicker");
}
```

Class "StartDatePickerFragment":

```
public class StartDatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment 
                    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fecha seleccionada: " + day + "/" + (month+1) + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Class "EndDatePickerFragment":

```
public class EndDatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

    LineGraph lineGraph = new LineGraph();
    lineGraph.run(getActivity());
}
}
```

I'm almost doing the same thing twice (creating the DatePicker), but I can't find a more efficient way.